# Extjs Combobox keeps resetting text-value when store loads no results

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I am working on a Search-As-You-Type component for Ext.js. It features AND-filtering several words, each chained in an OR-filtering against any properties of the records; subsequently.
When I type "Ke Ba" it will filter for "Kevin Bacon" and "Becky Kennedy".

I am loading the initial dataset in remote mode.

What happens is that the Data gets loaded into the store via my REST-Proxy and JSON Reader. Currently I do not "filter" on the server side but return everything and Mock the filterin in the client as if the dataset came filtered from the server. So it seems to the combobox.

Now when I change the search string to "Kre Ba", it will re-load from the REST-API (all data),  but the Store will be empty to the combobox as I don't have any records matching "Kre Ba".

Somehow Ext-js decides to reset the value of the combobox and the whole search-string disappears.

Is there a neat way to keep the searchstring even when the store has no matching Items (value-wise) after filtering?!

Here is the Ext.js code I found that resets the value:

```
 onLoad: function(store, records, success) {
    var me = this;

    if (me.ignoreSelection > 0) {
        --me.ignoreSelection;
    }

    // If not querying using the raw field value, we can set the value now we have data
    if (success && !store.lastOptions.rawQuery) {
        // Set the value on load

        // There's no value.
        if (me.value == null) {
            // Highlight the first item in the list if autoSelect: true
            if (me.store.getCount()) {
                me.doAutoSelect();
            } else {
                // assign whatever empty value we have to prevent change from firing
                me.setValue(me.value);
            }
        } else {
            me.setValue(me.value);
        }
    }
},
```

During debugging I find that `me.store.getCount()` returns `false` for the check.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my Combobox config:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.SearchAsYouTypeCombobox', {
extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
alias: 'widget.SearchAsYouTypeCombobox',

fieldLabel: 'Label',
hideLabel: true,
emptyText: 'Search',
hideTrigger: true,
minChars: 3,

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
            //some templates
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}

});
```

I am trying to build the component as a Controller where you only need to config a Combobox as View and a Store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.SearchAsYouTypeComboboxController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

stores: [
    'SearchAsYouTypeStore'
],
views: [
    'SearchAsYouTypeCombobox'
],

onComboboxBeforeQuery1: function(queryPlan, eOpts) {
    var me = this;
    //determine tokens
    //add filter per token

    //One could optimize by not clearing the filter when the query String is only extended (leading or trailing) and not changed.
    //consider maybe the tokens 

    //console.log('beforeQuery');
    var comboBox = queryPlan.combo;
    var myStore = comboBox.getStore(); 

    var queryString = queryPlan.query;
    var prevQueryString = comboBox.lastQuery || '';

    var words = Ext.String.splitWords(queryString);

    //var filterAllPropertiesFilter = {};


    console.log('Query String :' + queryString);
    console.log("Words: " + words);

    //console.log(Ext.JSON.encode(myStore.storeId));

    //myStore.clearFilter(true);

    if(!Ext.isEmpty(queryString))
    {
        var filters = [];


        //When query has not been only expanded
        if(prevQueryString && 
        (queryString.length <= prevQueryString.length || 
        queryString.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(prevQueryString.toLowerCase(), 0) !== 0))
        {
            //Reload everything new
            myStore.remoteFilter = true;
            myStore.clearFilter(true); //careful with this, it loads all the data unfiltered!


            myStore.remoteFilter = false;
            console.log('Creating Filters for each word.');
            Ext.Array.each(words,
            function(word, index, allWords){
                me.currentFilterWord = word;
                console.log('NEW FILTER: word:' + word);

                var filterAllPropertiesFilter = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter',
                    {filterString: word,
                    filterFn: me.filterAllPropertiesFn});
                filters.push(filterAllPropertiesFilter);

            });

        }
        else{   
            if(!prevQueryString){
                myStore.remoteFilter = true;
                myStore.clearFilter();
            }
            myStore.remoteFilter = false;

            //only for the last word
            me.currentFilterWord = words[words.length-1];
            console.log('NEW FILTER: word: ' + me.currentFilterWord);

            var filterAllPropertiesFilter = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter',
                {filterString: me.currentFilterWord,
                filterFn: me.filterAllPropertiesFn});

            filters.push(filterAllPropertiesFilter);
            Ext.Array.each(myStore.filters.items,
            function(filter, index, allFilters){
                myStore.removeFilter(filter, false);
            });
            //myStore.filter(filterAllPropertiesFilter);
        }

        myStore.filter(filters);
        comboBox.lastQuery = queryString;
        //filterBy(filters);
    }
    else
    {
        myStore.clearFilter(false);
    }

    comboBox.expand();
    queryPlan.cancel = true;
    return queryPlan;
},

filterAllPropertiesFn: function(item) {
    // filter magic
},

filterOverride: function(filters, value) {
    //changed the filter to subsequently filter 
},

init: function(application) {
    var me = this;
    console.log("init of Controller");

    //when more than 1 store then error
    console.log("Stores: " + this.stores[0]);

    var myStoreName = this.stores[0];
    var MyStore = me.getStore(myStoreName);

    console.log("MyStore: " + MyStore.storeId);

    Ext.override(MyStore,{override: myStoreName,
    filter: me.filterOverride});

    var myComboBoxName = this.views[0];
    var MyComboBox = me.getView(myComboBoxName);

    console.log("MyComboName: " + myComboBoxName);
    console.log("Data: " + MyStore.data.collect('id'));

    MyComboBox.store = MyStore;
    Ext.override(MyComboBox, {override: myComboBoxName,
    store: MyStore});

    console.log("myCombo.store: " + MyComboBox.store.storeId);


    this.control({
        "combobox": {
            beforequery: this.onComboboxBeforeQuery1,
        }
    });
},
});
```

Comment: What does your combobox config look like?  i.e. do you have lastQuery: '', triggerAction: 'all' and forceSelection: false set?

Comment: I have added them in the question. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I made some trial and error...

It seems to work know with these changes to the comboboxes `beforequery` method. But somehow it does not "autoselect" the first match after the first local filtering, anymore.

```
    onComboboxBeforeQuery1: function(queryPlan, eOpts) {
    var me = this;

    var comboBox = queryPlan.combo;
    var myStore = comboBox.getStore(); 

    var queryString = queryPlan.query;
    var prevQueryString = comboBox.lastQuery || '';

    var words = Ext.String.splitWords(queryString);

    console.log('Query String :' + queryString);
    console.log("Words: " + words);A


    if(!Ext.isEmpty(queryString))
    {
        var filters = [];


        //When query string has not just only expanded
        if(prevQueryString && 
        (queryString.length <= prevQueryString.length || 
        queryString.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(prevQueryString.toLowerCase(), 0) !== 0))
        {
            //Reload everything new
            //myStore.remoteFilter = true;
            myStore.clearFilter(false);
            //myStore.load();


            //myStore.remoteFilter = false;
            console.log('Creating Filters for each word.');
            Ext.Array.each(words,
            function(word, index, allWords){
                me.currentFilterWord = word;
                console.log('NEW FILTER: word:' + word);

                var filterAllPropertiesFilter = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter',
                    {filterString: word,
                    filterFn: me.filterAllPropertiesFn});
                filters.push(filterAllPropertiesFilter);

            });

        }
        else{   
            if(!prevQueryString){
                myStore.remoteFilter = true;
                myStore.clearFilter();
            }
            myStore.remoteFilter = false;

            //only for the last word
            me.currentFilterWord = words[words.length-1];
            console.log('NEW FILTER: word: ' + me.currentFilterWord);

            var filterAllPropertiesFilter = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter',
                {filterString: me.currentFilterWord,
                filterFn: me.filterAllPropertiesFn});

            filters.push(filterAllPropertiesFilter);
            Ext.Array.each(myStore.filters.items,
            function(filter, index, allFilters){
                myStore.removeFilter(filter, false);
            });
        }

        myStore.filter(filters);
        comboBox.lastQuery = queryString;
    }
    else
    {
        myStore.clearFilter(false);
    }

    comboBox.expand();
    queryPlan.cancel = true;
    return queryPlan;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do too much. If you're extending the combobox, why don't you just override the one function you need to use?

For example, I have similar functionality as you want for your combobox in someting I wrote.  I have a store for a combo on autoLoad to get the data.  After that, if I type anything it forces doLocalQuery to be fired since I have queryMode: 'local'.  I am overriding that function and replacing one section:

```
    var me = this,
        queryString = queryPlan.query,
        picker = me.getPicker();

    /** 
     * @author tjohnston
     * added queryPlan to combo so we can use it later 
     * added query and caseSensitive to picker (boundlist) to use in highlighting
     */
    me.queryPlan = queryPlan;
    picker.query = queryString;
    picker.caseSensitive = me.caseSensitive;

    // Create our filter when first needed
    if (!me.queryFilter) {
        // Create the filter that we will use during typing to filter the Store
        me.queryFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
            id: me.id + '-query-filter',
            anyMatch: me.anyMatch,
            combo: me,
            caseSensitive: me.caseSensitive,
            root: 'data',
            /**
             * removed property as we're using filterFn
             * added filterFn functionality 
             */
            /** property: me.displayField, **/
            filterFn: function(rec) {
                return me.filterFn(me,rec);
            }
        });
        me.store.addFilter(me.queryFilter, false);
    }
```

This then it turn calls 2 functions:

```
/** @public **/
/** config for any instance we create if we want to override. **/
filterTest: function(combo,str,regex,rec) {
    return regex.test(rec.data[combo.displayField]);
},

/** @private **/
/** our filter function for **/
filterFn: function(combo,rec) {
    var me = this,
        queryPlan = combo.queryPlan,
        anyMatch = me.anyMatch,
        caseSensitive = me.caseSensitive ? '' : 'i',
        queryString = anyMatch ? queryPlan.query.split(/\s+/) : '^'+queryPlan.query,
        total = queryString.length,
        isNoMatch = 0,
        isMatch = 0,
        i = 0;

    /** make sure we filter for each text string in the query **/
    Ext.each(queryString, function(str) {
        if (str !== '') {
        //if (str !== '' && str.length >= combo.minChars) {
            var query = new RegExp(str,caseSensitive+'g');
            if (combo.filterTest(combo,str,query,rec)) {
                isMatch++;
            } else {
                isNoMatch++;
            }
        }
    });

    if (isNoMatch > 0) {
        /** we match in OR so if we have one match from any query word, return true **/
        if (combo.orMatch == true && isMatch > 0 ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
},
```

Comment: `combo.queryPlan` seems not to be defined. Am I missing a config option on the combo? Otherwise I would just set it in the beforeQuery for now.

Comment: Also this solution applies all filters on the "loaded" record everytime. It has no Agenda of subsequently loosing record while the search-string is only extended (not changed in the middle).

Comment: You can ignore combo.queryPlan.  I added it before the line (!me.queryFilter). If you want add it above:      me.queryPlan = queryPlan; picker.query = queryString; picker.caseSensitive = me.caseSensitive;

Comment: If you're not filtering on the server side, the data should only be retrieved once.  All subsequent typing in the combobox should filter locally.  There is no reason to get server side data every time unless you're loading in completely different records that aren't in the intial store data load.

Comment: That's true and exactly what I wanted. 
But when you have a lot of records to filter it might be good to not always filter against all records that came from the server, especially when you have several words to check.
I've slightly changed it to not check against the data
 snapshot of the server, but rather manipulate the data and drop locally what does not match. And always validate the string for changes that suggest reloading from snapshot or from server.

Comment: How many records are you talking? Your minChars is 3.  I've done over 1500 records and it wasn't a problem with multiple words to search on.  The code I gave you should work fine for that.  If you are trying to do a lot more records, lets say 3000+, then you probably need to do a remote filter.  Either way, you shouldn't have to manipulate any data.  Based on what I gave you, you either return true if it matches, false if it doesn't.  The combox logic will take care of the rest.

Comment: It is to become a general component. So the number of records and filters is arbitrary. But in general you have a point. When there are too many records x filter operations the remote filter should be more limiting or paging. But I think I found a way. Right now I'm working on something else. When I come back to it I'll post it.